# Matlab: issues by using try and catch in a system string calling a m-file

Tags: matlab

I order to test if expressions are valid or not I generate m-files P_prim_name = 'test_verification.m' containing an expression and an evaluation command:

```
F = '(z+((z.^2)-1)^2)';
z = 2; Matlab_return = eval(F);
```

I want to call those files from a main Matlab program and return the numeric variable value of Matlab_return if the expression is valid or a non-numeric string like 'error' if the expression is invalid. (The distinction between a numeric and a non-numeric value is important to identify if the expression is valid or not with isnumeric(Matlab_return)). In order to do this I try constructing a system-string like:

```
Matlab_systemstring = strcat('matlab -nodesktop -r "try, run(''', P_prim_name, '''); ... 
catch Matlab_return=''error''; save(''test_verification_result'', ''Matlab_return''); end, exit"');
```

It is supposed that the value of Matlab_return is saved in a mat-file and is retrieved in the main program by

```
load('test_verification_result.mat');
```

If the expression is invalid the mat-file  is indeed  generated with the value 'error'. But if the expression is valid no mat-file is generated at all (assuming I have the one deleted that was generated before):

```
Error using load
Unable to read file 'test_verification_result.mat'. No such file or directory.
```

If I use another sequence for test purpose

```
"try, run(''', P_prim_name, '''); save(''test_verification_result'', ''Matlab_return''); ... 
catch Matlab_return=''error'';  end, exit"
```

and the expression is valid then the mat-file will be generated with the right numeric value. But if I change the expression to get an invalid one no mat-file will be generated.

What should I do to get in all cases a mat-file with a numeric value if the expression is valid and an non-numeric string if it is invalid?

Clarification: I am generating expressions with a GP'ish (genetic programming) process and I want to test if an offspring candidate has a valid Matlab syntax directly after it is generated. This implies that in the case it is invalid the main process can not be disturbed which results in a kind of solution with a child process I think.

Comment: Why do you need to jump through all of these hoops just to see if an expression is valid? There are a lot of better ways. You can use `mlint` to check for parse errors. You can use `str2func` to generate a function handle. And why not loop within MATLAB rather than making another call out to MATLAB at the system level? It may be worth explaining what you're actually trying to do at a higher level because you seem to have painted yourself into a corner of hot lava.

Comment: That being said, the issue is that you don't have a semicolon after `catch`. Also your `catch` is in the wrong place because you save the output within the catch block rather than within the try block

Comment: "don't have a semicolon after catch": In both strings I have a semicolon "catch Matlab_return=''error'';"

Comment: "output within the catch block rather than within the try block": In the first string I have the sequence "try run catch save end exit" and in the second string "try run save catch end exit". Where should I place "save" then (if you associate output with save)?

Comment: "jump through all of these hoops": I am totally open to all alternatives where huge sets of expressions can automatically checked (I need only binary classification not any specific error messages). I just looked at (the not recommended) mlint and checkcode, and I can not see how to analyze potentially page long lists of messages to get such a binary decision.

Comment: "And why not loop within MATLAB": how can I loop in Matlab when the main program is stopped after an invalid expression is recognized? This is not a rhetorical question!

Comment: You need a semincolon after `catch`: `catch; Matlab_return='error';`

Comment: Where are your expressions stored?

Comment: applying catch; 1) Matlab_systemstring = strcat('matlab -nodesktop -r "try, run(''', P_prim_name, '''); catch; Matlab_return=''error''; save(''test_verification_result'', ''Matlab_return''); end, exit"');  result: valid=>nosave invalid=>Matlab_return=error

Comment: applying catch; 2) Matlab_systemstring = strcat('matlab -nodesktop -r "try, run(''', P_prim_name, '''); save(''test_verification_result'', ''Matlab_return''); catch; Matlab_return=''error''; end, exit"'); result: valid=>save invalid=>nosave

Comment: I delete  'test_verification_result.mat' if it exists before calling and Matlab_systemstring = strcat('matlab -nodesktop -r "try, run(''', P_prim_name, '''); catch Matlab_return=''error''; end, save(''test_verification_result'', ''Matlab_return''); exit"'); seems to work for a few test cases at least (valid=>save invalid=>Matlab_return=error). Will test it further.

Comment: "Where are your expressions stored": I am testing now verification direct after expression is generated. Batch job of testing an expression population stored in a file is only second best approach